# Magento how to fetch row by row like PDO::fetch()

Tags: database, mysql, ce-1.9.0.1

I am running

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT id FROM customers_old";
$old_customers = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

But it's a HUGH table and this does not fit into memory:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Normally I would make a loop an fetch row by row: `$connection->fetch($sql)`

But fetch does not exist here and `fetchRow()` always returns the same row.

Solution?

Comment: If you are pulling that much data into PHP to process it then you are asking for trouble from the offset.  Look for a better more memory efficient way to achieve the same result and pull only the data you need from the database.  Also, importantly, you should be working with a collection in the situation above - using MySQL directly is a big no-no particularly as Magento is already a good way down the road to supporting multiple databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the core/resource_iterator. This passes each object in a collection through a callback method. This article from Atwix (I'm not connected to them in any way) explains it really well: http://www.atwix.com/magento/working-with-large-collections/.

Comment: Note: this answer forgoes record set iteration and instead uses OO collection walking. Useful 99% of the time, but if you know what you're doing and actually *want* to use PDO-style iteration, see Renon Stewart's answer below.

Comment: This is helpful, but you should always explain and excerpt the code in your answer while citing the source in case the link goes dead later.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [How to convert sql query to magento in order to fetch data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19863/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-magento-in-order-to-fetch-data)

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$readresult = $read->query("SELECT id FROM customers_old");

while ($row = $readresult->fetch() ) {
    $Ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

See [Conquer the 5 Most 
Common Magento Coding 
Issues to Optimize Your Site 
for Performance](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf)

Comment: REALLY don't recommend this approach.

Comment: Good code! But DO NOT try to be smart and add it to 1 line like this `while ($row = $read->query($select)->fetch())` as it will create an infinite loop, and this I have no idea why.

Comment: @Shadowbob look at what fetch returns and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

> $tableName = 'customer_entity_varchar';
>
> $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
>
> $qry = "SELECT * FROM  $tableName WHERE value =  240";
>
> $result = $db->query($qry);
>
> **$data =  $result->fetchAll();**
>
> echo '';print_r($data);

Try this, you can get this data in array format, if you wants to get single data then use **$result->fetch()**